# What's the proper way to hide any HTML tag?

Tags: html, css

What is Proper CSS for hiding any HTML. Example- Like `<div>` tag.
I use to do this:

```
div {display:none; visibility:hidden;}
```

Does the CSS Supports all the major browsers to Hide that div. Especially Does it Support I.E.

Comment: See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility.  Avoid using `hidden`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` are universally supported by CSS-enabled browsers, so only the general [CSS caveat](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css-caveats.html)s apply. The have different effect: `display:none` causes the document to be rendered as if the element were not there at all, whereas `visibility:hidden` means that the element will be duly processed when formatting the document, normally occupying some space, but removed from the view as if it were turned completely transparent.

Which one you use depends on your goal of hiding an element. For example, if you dynamically (with a client-side script) switch off or on some content, then `visibility:hidden` can be better as it does not cause a redraw of other content.

Using both is normally pointless, as `display:none` makes `visibility:hidden` irrelevant (though in the cascade, it might happen that your settings for these properties may be overridden by other style sheets, and then `display:none` may lose effect).

Answer (score 23):

Use `visibility: hidden;` if you still want the element to take up space in the page layout.  For example:

```html
Hello
<div style="visibility: hidden; height: 100px;">Hidden</div>
World
```

You will still see 100px between the two pieces of text, but you will not see the contents within the div.

Using:

```html
Hello
<div style="display: none; height: 100px;">Hidden</div>
World​​​​​
```

There will be no space between the two text elements, as the `div` will not affect the layout at all.

Both are supported in any modern browser you can think of.

Answer (score 9):

You don't even need `visibility:hidden;`.

```
div {
    display:none;
}
```

The above should be enough. And it works in all browsers. It pretty much hides the element completely, as in, it will no longer have an influence in page layout.

Answer (score 4):

In **HTML5** there is a new global attribute called `hidden`.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden :

> The hidden global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant. For example, it can be used to hide elements of the page that can't be used until the login process has been completed. Browsers won't render elements with the hidden attribute set.

Beware that `hidden` has a semantic meaning compared to `display` and `visibility`. That is why it is not a CSS attribute, but an HTML attribute.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you use css `display:none`, then when it's time to toggle it back into view, then sometimes you have to use `display:block` or `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`. Alternatively you can define a class called `hidden` and toggle the class on/off. But I believe the `hidden` html attribute is a more standard way to do things.

Comment: True, `<element hidden>` works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

`display : none;`
is enough and standard way to do this